# How to Unit Test DelegateCommand that calls async methods in MVVM

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mvvm, prism, delegatecommand

I am new to Unit Testing MVVM and using PRISM on my project. I am implementing Unit Testing on our current project and not having luck finding resources online that would tell me how totest DelegateCommand that calls async method. This is a follow up question to my post - [How to Unit Test a ViewModel with async method.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631635/how-to-unit-test-a-viewmodel-with-async-method) on how to unit test an async methods in MVVM and was answered that public methods can be tested using async TestMethod. This scenario will work only if the method that I want to test are public methods.

The problem is I want to test my DelegateCommand as this are the only public details that I want to expose on other classes and everything else are private. I can expose my private methods as public but I will never do this as its a bad design. I am not sure on how to go about this - Is DelegateCommand needs to be tested, or there are some other work around this? I am interested to know how other go about this and somehow lead me to the right path.

Here are my codes again

```
 async void GetTasksAsync()
        {
            this.SimpleTasks.Clear();
            Func<IList<ISimpleTask>> taskAction = () =>
                {
                    var result = this.dataService.GetTasks();
                    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                        return null;
                    return result;
                };
            IsBusyTreeView = true;

            Task<IList<ISimpleTask>> getTasksTask = Task<IList<ISimpleTask>>.Factory.StartNew(taskAction, token);
            var l = await getTasksTask;          // waits for getTasksTask


            if (l != null)
            {
                foreach (ISimpleTask t in l)
                {
                    this.SimpleTasks.Add(t); // adds to ViewModel.SimpleTask
                }
            }
        }
```

also here is the command in my VM that calls the async method above

```
  this.GetTasksCommand = new DelegateCommand(this.GetTasks);
      void GetTasks()
        {
                GetTasksAsync();
        }
```

and now my Test Method goes like

```
 [TestMethod]
        public void Command_Test_GetTasksCommand()
        {
          MyViewModel.GetTaskCommand.Execute(); // this should populate ViewModel.SimpleTask 
          Assert.IsTrue(MyBiewModel.SimpleTask != null)
        }
```

Currently what I am getting is that my ViewModel.SimpleTask = null this is because it does not wait for the async method to finish.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I wrote an AsyncCommand class that returns a Task object from the `Execute` method. You then need to implement `ICommand.Execute` explicitly, awaiting the Task from your `Execute` implementation:

```
public class AsyncCommand : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public Func<Task> ExecutedHandler { get; private set; }

    public Func<bool> CanExecuteHandler { get; private set; }

    public AsyncCommand(Func<Task> executedHandler, Func<bool> canExecuteHandler = null)
    {
        if (executedHandler == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("executedHandler");
        }

        this.ExecutedHandler = executedHandler;
        this.CanExecuteHandler = canExecuteHandler;
    }

    public Task Execute()
    {
        return this.ExecutedHandler();
    }

    public bool CanExecute()
    {
        return this.CanExecuteHandler == null || this.CanExecuteHandler();
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        if (this.CanExecuteChanged != null)
        {
            this.CanExecuteChanged(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return this.CanExecute();
    }

    async void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
    {
        await this.Execute();
    }
}
```

You can then pass async Task-returning methods to the command class:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public AsyncCommand AsyncCommand { get; private set; }

    public bool Executed { get; private set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Executed = false;
        AsyncCommand = new AsyncCommand(Execute);
    }

    private async Task Execute()
    {
        await(Task.Delay(1000));
        Executed = true;
    }
}
```

In your unit tests, you simply await the `Execute` method:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestAsyncCommand()
{
    var viewModel = new ViewModel();

    Assert.IsFalse(viewModel.Executed);
    await viewModel.AsyncCommand.Execute();

    Assert.IsTrue(viewModel.Executed);
}
```

The UI, on the other hand, will call the explicitly implemented `ICommand.Execute` method which takes care of awaiting the task.

(*) In the meantime I noticed that if you follow common naming conventions, the Task-returning method should actually be named `ExecuteAsync`.

Answer (score 0):

In Prism 6, you can create `DelegateCommand` and `DelegateCommand<T>` from async handler.

For example:

`startParsingCommand=DelegateCommand
   .FromAsyncHandler(StartParsingAsync,CanStartParsing)
   .ObservesProperty(()=> IsParserStarted);`

Comment: FromAsyncHandler is obsoleted in Prism 6.x ( I don't know which x :D ), so any better way for do this?

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot add comments, for completeness sake, in PRISM 6 you could try:

```
ParsingCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(async (x) => await StartParsing(x));
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is how to test `DelegateCommand` which executes `async` handler, not how to create such command.