# Wait for async method without blocking the thread

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, .net-4.5, async-await

How can i execute the `UpdateTasklist()` Method after the `SubmitWorkitem()` Method without blocking the thread?

```
private async void SubmitWorkitem(Workitem workitem)
{
    await Task.Run(() => this.SubmitWorkitem(workitem));

    //UpdateTasklist() should be executed after SubmitWorkitem() method.
    //How can i achieve this without blocking the UI thread?
    var locator = new ViewModelLocator();
    locator.Task.UpdateTasklist();
}
```

**EDIT:**

The `UpdateTasklist()` method connects to an wcf webservice and asks for all open workitems. The workitem which is submitted in the `SubmitWorkitem()` Method is still part of the reply. I thought that would be because `UpdateTasklist()` is executed before the submission of the workitem is done.

Note that `UpdateTasklist()` is also an async method

Comment: Either define a callback, or put `UpdateTaskList` in the async task

Comment: edited my answer re your edit

Comment: ooh, just noticed that this is `async void`; yeah... don't do that; that is simply dangerous. That feature *only* exists to allow for event handlers; you should never write an `async void` method out of choice; it should be `async Task` or `async Task<SomeType>`

Comment: i guess i've learned something today, thank you for this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Important: **DO NOT WRITE `ASYNC VOID` METHODS** (unless you are writing an event-handler)

For the rest:

That is already what happens in your code; this is what `await` *means*; basically, your `DifferentClass.UpdateTasklist();` method happens as part of the *continuation* that gets invoked when *and only when* the first task (`this.SubmitWorkitem(workitem)`) completes.

With your edit, there *is* a missing step: you should `await` the second method, otherwise the method cannot report completion / failure (IIRC the compiler will also nag you):

```
private async Task SubmitWorkitem(Workitem workitem)
{
    await Task.Run(() => this.SubmitWorkitem(workitem));
    var locator = new ViewModelLocator();
    await locator.Task.UpdateTasklist();
}
```

Comment: the method has to be void because of this:  this.SubmitCommand = new RelayCommand(this.SubmitWorkitem, this.CanSubmit);

Comment: @Joel hmmm, I guess that has to come under the same bracket as event-handlers then; perhaps the correct guidance is "do not write an async void method unless you have no alternative" - however, keep in mind that the runner here will have *no clue* whether your method has finished yet - as far as the framework is concerned, the method will be "over" at the point it reaches the first `await` (if we assume that the awaited operation doesn't actually finish synchronously, which can happen, but which sounds unlikely here). The point being ... perhaps expect trouble

Comment: @Joel: You do need an `async void` `ICommand.Execute` implementation in this case, but you can "hide" it behind an `async Task` method. This gives you a better API which you can consume directly, e.g., when unit testing. A simple `AsyncCommand` type is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15743118/263693) and I wrote a more complex one [here](https://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Source/Nito.AsyncEx.Mvvm%20(NET45,%20Win8,%20SL4,%20WP75)/AsyncCommand.cs).