# What is my mistake in implementing an asynchronous RelayCommand?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, async-await, mvvm-light

I am learning WPF and MVVM at the moment and I faced a problem when i tried to write unit tests for a viewmodel, whose commands invoke `async` methods. That problem is well-described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727515/how-to-unit-test-delegatecommand-that-calls-async-methods-in-mvvm) question. That question also has a solution: to write a new Command class with an additional awaitable method that can be awaited in unit tests. But since i use MvvmLight, i decided not to write a new class, but to inherit from the built-in `RelayCommand` class instead. However, i don't seem to understand how to do it properly. Below is a simplified example that illustrates my problem:

**AsyncRelayCommand:**

```
public class AsyncRelayCommand : RelayCommand
{
    private readonly Func<Task> _asyncExecute;

    public AsyncRelayCommand(Func<Task> asyncExecute)
        : base(() => asyncExecute())
    {
        _asyncExecute = asyncExecute;
    }

    public AsyncRelayCommand(Func<Task> asyncExecute, Action execute)
        : base(execute)
    {
        _asyncExecute = asyncExecute;
    }
    
    public Task ExecuteAsync()
    {
        return _asyncExecute();
    }

    //Overriding Execute like this fixes my problem, but the question remains unanswered.
    //public override void Execute(object parameter)
    //{
    //    _asyncExecute();
    //}
}
```

**My ViewModel (based on the default MvvmLight MainViewModel):**

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _welcomeTitle = "Welcome!";

    public string WelcomeTitle
    {
        get
        {
            return _welcomeTitle;
        }

        set
        {
            _welcomeTitle = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("WelcomeTitle");
        }
    }

    public AsyncRelayCommand Command { get; private set; }
    public MainViewModel(IDataService dataService)
    {
        Command = new AsyncRelayCommand(CommandExecute); //First variant
        Command = new AsyncRelayCommand(CommandExecute, () => CommandExecute()); //Second variant
    }

    private async Task CommandExecute()
    {
        WelcomeTitle = "Command in progress";
        await Task.Delay(1500);
        WelcomeTitle = "Command completed";
    }
}
```

As far as i understand it, both First and Second variants should invoke different constructors, but lead to the same result. However, only the second variant works the way i expect it to. The first one behaves strangely, for example, if i press the button, that is binded to `Command` once, it works ok, but if i try to press it a second time a few seconds later, it simply does nothing.

My understanding of `async` and `await` is far from complete. Please explain me why the two variants of instantiating the `Command` property behave so differently.

P.S.: this behavior is noticeable only when i inherit from `RelayCommand`. A newly created class that implements `ICommand` and has the same two constructors works as expected.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that's your exact code? I can't see anything that would cause that behavior. However, any exceptions from `CommandExecute` would be silently ignored with this approach.

Comment: There is no "one size fits all" solution for `async` MVVM commands, but I describe a few approaches in [my MSDN article on the subject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630647.aspx).

Comment: @StephenCleary Thanks for your response. That is my exact code, i am sure of that. I tried to reproduce the problem without inheriting from `RelayCommand`, in a simple `DelegateCommand` class with the same two constuctors, but it worked as expected. I solved my problem by overriding `Execute` to make it use `_asyncExecute`. But that does not answer my question, since i still can't understand the strange behavior.

Comment: I also added the code of my simplified ViewModel.

Comment: It looks like root of the problem is `RelayCommand`'s use of `WeakAction`, which allows the owner of that action to be garbage collected. I suspect the difference in behavior is caused by the different location of the `async` state machine.

Comment: @StephenCleary Indeed, i ended up browsing `RelayCommand` source and that gave me the same answer. The check `(_execute.IsStatic || _execute.IsAlive)` clearly returns `false` in my case. Thanks for your help! (i will definitely read your article to understand the whole topic better).

Comment: Eerily similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25868209/relaycommand-stops-working-after-a-while

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OK, I think I found the problem. `RelayCommand` uses a `WeakAction` to allow the owner (target) of the `Action` to be garbage collected. I'm not sure why they made this design decision.

So, in the working example where the `() => CommandExecute()` is in the view model constructor, the compiler is generating a private method on your constructor that looks like this:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private void <.ctor>b__0()
{
  this.CommandExecute();
}
```

Which works fine because the view model is not eligible for garbage collection.

However, in the odd-behavior example where the `() => asyncExecute()` is in the constructor, the lambda closes over the `asyncExecute` variable, causing a *separate type* to be created for that closure:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private sealed class <>c__DisplayClass2
{
  public Func<Task> asyncExecute;

  public void <.ctor>b__0()
  {
    this.asyncExecute();
  }
}
```

This time, the actual target of the `Action` is an instance of `<>c__DisplayClass2`, which is never saved anywhere. Since `WeakAction` only saves a weak reference, the instance of that type is eligible for garbage collection, and that's why it stops working.

If this analysis is correct, then you should always either pass a local method to `RelayCommand` (i.e., do not create lambda closures), or capture a (strong) reference to the resulting `Action` yourself:

```
private readonly Func<Task> _asyncExecute;
private readonly Action _execute;

public AsyncRelayCommand(Func<Task> asyncExecute)
    : this(asyncExecute, () => asyncExecute())
{
}

private AsyncRelayCommand(Func<Task> asyncExecute, Action execute)
    : base(execute)
{
  _asyncExecute = asyncExecute;
  _execute = execute;
}
```

Note that this actually has nothing to do with `async`; it's purely a question of lambda closures. I suspect it's the same underlying issue as [this one regarding lambda closures with `Messenger`](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/workitem/7640).

Comment: Thanks for the analysis and the answer!

Comment: Like you said - nothing to do with async. This happened to me because I was using a parameter from the constructor in a `RelayCommand` body defined by a lambda. As soon as I saved it as an instance property the weak reference wasn't killed (made to be `IsAlive=false`)